# Is float value guaranteed to be 0 when a float variable is initialized to 0.0?

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy, processor

In C, on any micro controller when we initialize a float variable to 0

```
float var = 0.0f;
```

Is 'var' exactly equal to zero or does it depend on the min & max float resolution of the processor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Happily, zero is actually zero no matter what: IEEE-754 (the usual standard for floats) sets aside the all-zeroes bit pattern as meaning identically zero.

Comment: the question is about "any micro controller". is "exact zero" guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: Yes. Zero is a value which can always be represented exactly in IEEE-754. I have never worked with a system (embedded or otherwise) that used any other type of `float`.

Comment: To be specific, my question was aimed at MPC 5554. So DSP may not be an issue for me right now. Thanks for the information though.