# Using extern with multidimentional arrays in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, extern

I have a bunch of multidimensional arrays that are allocated in local functions in different source files, but I want to make them global. I was thinking of using `extern` and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files), I need to make a header file that includes the *declaration* of my variable and then *define* that variable, only once, within one of the source files.

However, the method I'm using to generate multidimensional arrays both declares and defines the variable in one line, like so:

```
float (*data0)[224][3] = calloc(224, sizeof *data0);
```

Is there a way I can split this into declaration and definition so that I can use this method, or would it be better to just do both at the header file itself?

---

I am making a neural network implementation in C and I have a lot of those arrays defined in multiple places. At first I didn't think I would need them at a later point, and this is supposed to run in an embedded system with memory constraints, so I made these arrays all local and used `free` on them as soon as possible.

But it turns out I will need them for the training of this network so I need them to be global so that they save their values over many iterations of the functions. Plus, I didn't know that the system we will use will have a 64MB DRAM attached to it, so memory constraints are not as much of a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're defining these arrays globally, there's no need to dynamically allocate memory.  Unlike stack space, there's no practical limit to how big globals can be.

So assuming you want a 3D array with dimensions 224, 224, and 3, define it as follows:

```
float data0[224][224][3];
```

Then declare it in your header file as:

```
extern float data0[224][224][3];
```

Also, globals are zero-initialized by default, so no need for an explicit initializer.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  You might want to point out that, since it's a global, you already get zero initialization of the arrays, just as `calloc` provides. (C99 6.7. 8.10)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah, I see, thanks, I was about to ask about that. However, is that initialization to the *bytes* of each variable, like `calloc` does, or does it set the *values* of the floats to zero?

Comment: @Ricardo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28601320: *"Happily, zero is actually zero no matter what: IEEE-754 (the usual standard for floats) sets aside the all-zeroes bit pattern as meaning identically zero."*

Comment: @Ricardo According to the C standard the values are set to +0, however if your system uses IEEE754 floating point representation then the bytes are also 0.

Comment: I understand, thanks, this answers all my questions then.